# Evaluate Infinite Sums

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I'm having trouble with this question.

$$E=\sum_0^\infty \frac{nhve^{-nx}}{\sum_0^\infty e^{-nx}}$$

where x=(hv)/(kT)

Evaluate both sums and show that E=hv(e^x -1)^-1

I've tried comparing \sum_0^/infty${e^(-nx)}$ to geometric series and expanding the sums but I am unsure how to continue. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to fix it but it didn't show up with the actual sign for the sum still.

Comment: Finally got it, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a useful link: http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php

Comment: I guess it's
$$
{\displaystyle\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}nh\nu\exp\left(\,-\,{nh\nu \over KT}\,\right) \over \displaystyle\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\exp\left(\,-\,{nh\nu \over KT}\,\right)}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** Let $f(t)=\sum_0^\infty e^{-nt}$. Note this is a geometric series with first term $1$ and common ratio $e^{-t}$. If $t$ is positive it has sum $\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}$.

Differentiate the series for $f(t)$ term by term. We get $\sum_0^\infty -ne^{-nt}$. So by differentiating $\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}$ we can get an expression for the sum on top.

Finally, substitute the known value of $x$ for $t$.